# Two unicode code-points when using json_write()?

Tags: jquery, c++, json, unicode, boost-propertytree

When using `boost::property_tree::write_json()` to write a JSON file, all unicode characters will be represented as two "/u"-code points.

- So `ä` will become `\u00C3\u00A4`.

My problem is, that I am generating a JSON file which will be read via JQuery to be shown in a web page. In that case, this pair will be shown as two separated unicode symbols.

- So `ä` looks like `Ã¤`

Is there a way to configure the output encoding to get a single Utf16 code point? Or is there a way to tell jQuery to use both code-points as one?

Also, why is `ä` becoming `\u00C3\u00A4` instead of `\u00E4`? I really don't get it.

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 1):

That's because it's encoded as "UTF-8", if the output comes out wrong like that, it's either because it's been encoded twice, or because it's not being "understood" as UTF-8. Which is probably because the web-page is not correctly set up to say "use UTF-8". Your header on the page will need to have `Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8` or something along those lines.